# Can someone help me with the solution to Project Euler #4 in Java?

Tags: java

Okay guys, I know that this is not the most elegant solution for Project Euler's 4th problem, but I'm proud of it because I did it by myself... until now.

Here is the problem for reference:
http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=4

```
public class Problem4 {

    public void projectEuler4() {
        int answer = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
                if (i * j >= answer) {
                    String stringNum = "" + answer;
                    String firstHalf = "";
                    String secondHalf = "";
                    if (stringNum.length() % 2 == 0) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < stringNum.length() / 2; k++) {
                            firstHalf = firstHalf + ("" + stringNum.charAt(k));
                        }
                        for (int k = stringNum.length(); k < stringNum.length() / 2; k--) {
                            secondHalf = secondHalf + ("" + stringNum.charAt(k));
                        }
                        if (Integer.parseInt(firstHalf) == Integer.parseInt(secondHalf)) {
                            answer = i * j;
                            System.out.println(answer);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome challenge! But what do you want from us? :D

Comment: "There is a tiny problem and I've been pulling my hair out looking for it."  It would help if you told us what the problem was!

Comment: Whoa, that's a lot of indentation levels.

Comment: Ah well: Im gonna do that challenge too :D Nice

Comment: To speed it up a bit, you could start with higher numbers (make your outer loop start high) and you can skip repeats by starting or ending your inner loop early.  e.g. if you've done 1 * 2, no need to do 2 * 1.

Answer (score 1):

This code `for(int k = stringNum.length(); k < stringNum.length()/2; k--)`

You have the comparison messed up (< instead of >) and also you start from stringNum.length(), while the last character is at position stringNum.length() - 1.

However there are a lot of things you can improve codewise:

1. No need to do `"abc"+(""+'d')`, you can directly do `"abc"+'d'`
2. No need to `Integer.parseInt("123") == Integer.parseInt("123")`, you can directly do `"123".equals("123")`

Comment: `"123"=="123"` should be `"123".equals("123")` because `==` tests reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop

```
for(int k = stringNum.length(); k < stringNum.length()/2; k--)
```

you are counting down so your terminating condition is wrong